# Как возможно провести интеграцию сайта на PHP Symfony2 в Salesforce?

Tags: symfony, api, php

Как возможно провести интеграцию сайта на PHP Symfony2 в Salesforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rtfm и гугл: [PHP Integration with Salesforce CRM](http://epixa.com/2010/05/php-integration-with-salesforce-crm.html)